# Conditional Multiplication Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need to multiply some values depending on a string value of a list.

If there is no previous value, it has to take the first value of the list, if there is already a value it has to multiply it with the previous value.

The desired result is seen on the b8 cell, for the first value of the list. But this one is made manually. I hope I've explained well, and the picture helps a better understand.

Google Sheet with the list, formulas and expected result:

[image: Google Sheet with the list, formulas and expected result]

Comment: I think you'll need to explain the problem in more detail. This is not clear.

Comment: Ok Ill try it again. I'm trying to multiply some values depending of the first name of a list. On the example shown in the picture, as far as I have 2 or more reference on the ticker column of the same name I have to multiply their value so in the case shown, E3*E4 for APPS and put it on cell D12, as ROKU it's only one time on the list, I have to get its own value and put it on the D13 cell. I hope this explanation helps you. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

D12: `=product(filter(E3:E5,B3:B5="APPS"))`

D13: `=product(filter(E3:E5,B3:B5="ROKU"))`

Explanation:

- `filter(E3:E5,B3:B5="ROKU")` creates an array with values for just "APPS" or just "ROKU"
- `product` multiplies those values

Comment: thanks for your quick and effective response.I also tried it with query, which I discovered this morning, but product which you showed, was what make it work. =product(query(Posiciones,"select E where B = 'APPS'",0))